# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified en bash?

Tags: bash

> tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Estoy realizando un código en bash y no se me ejecuta correctamente. Creo que puede ser un error que se encuentra en el archivo *bashrc*.

```
    #!/bin/bash

   
    #Variables Globales


    function Unconfirmedtransactions()
    {
       echo '' > ut.tmp 

       while [ "$(cat ut.tmp | wc -l)" == "1" ]; do 
           curl -s "$unconfirmed_transactions" | html2text > ut.tmp
       done 

       hashes=$(cat ut.tmp | grep "Hash" -A 1 | grep -v -E "Hash|\- -|Time")

       echo $hashes

       tput cnorm
    }

    parameter_counter=0; while getopts "e:h:" arg; do
        case $arg in 
            e) exploration_mode=$OPTARG;let parameter_counter+=1;;
            h) helpPanel;;
        esac 
    done

    tput civis
```

Según parece la variable `$TERM` no tiene asignada ningún valor.

Comment: ¿que te dice `echo $TERM` desde tu bash?

Comment: [1] 8855

bash: TERM: orden no encontrada
[1]+  Hecho                   echo

Comment: Me sale: xterm-256color

Comment: como referencia `tput civis` oculta el cursor y `tput cnorm` lo restaura ( tput necesita saber que tipo de terminal es para poder lograr eso ), como alternativa podes testear `$TERM` para ver si hace falta usar esos comandos ( si no hay terminal no hay cursor y no hay `$TERM` )

Comment: Genial muchísimas gracias por tu aportación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tput` necesita un terminal donde mostrar la salida, y si tu script lo estas lanzando, por ejemplo, mediante `cron`, éste se ejecuta como usuario `root` sin tener terminal asignado.

Tienes algunas posibles soluciones:

1. Asignar `TERM` al valor `dump` antes de llamar a `tput` de este modo:

   ***TERM=dump***
2. Asignar `TERM` al valor actual que has mostrado en los comentarios:

   ***TERM=xterm-256color***
3. Pasarle el parámetro `-T` y especificarle un terminal, como por ejemplo, `-T xterm-256color`

   ***tput -T xterm-256color cnorm***

Si estás ejecutando tu script desde `cron` entonces tambien podrias poner esto al principio, sustituyendo `<terminal>` por `dump` o `xterm-256color` en tu caso:

```
TERM=<terminal>

* * * * * sh /ruta/a/tuscript.sh
```

Aunque lo cierto es que no parece adecuado usar `tput` dentro de un script que no va ejecutarse en un terminal y quizás deberias revisar para que lo estas usando y si va a cumplir con tu propósito realmente.